# Prevent ASP.NET(MVC) website to shutting down on exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, exception

I know that unhandled exceptions on background threads cause website shutting down so prevent website to shut down, I put below code code to Global.asax for prevent it.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    System.Exception ex = Context.Server.GetLastError();

    context.Server.ClearError();

    Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
}
```

But even this code doesn't prevent to website shut down. What I am missing in here ?

Comment: An exception in a page will not cause the whole site to go down. What do you mean by "background threads" in this case?

Comment: Manually creating threads like new Thread(()=> new ArgumentException()).Start()

Comment: There is no way in ASP.NET to prevent unhandled background exceptions from killing the process.  Your best bet is to handle the exception (if possible) at the thread entry point.  What kind of threads are these / what kinds of exceptions are being thrown?  If you describe your scenario a bit more we may be able to offer guidance.  Alternatively, you may wish to use Task.Run instead of spawning threads manually.

Comment: I want to prevent my website to shutting down because restart cause some performance overhead because i also do some expensive initialization jobs on global.asax side. Task will prevents shutting down if i prefer Task instead of using thread ?

Comment: The shutting down have to do with your settings on the pool. There you can set if for example 5 errors happens in 5 seconds to shut down the pool. Disable that there, or handle your errors with try/catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to manually spawn managed threads, I think the [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=vs.110%29.Aspx) event is your only choice for non-fatal exceptions since `Application_Error` does not get called for exceptions thrown outside the request processing context.

Depending on what you're doing in your background threads, you may want to switch to the [async/await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) model for I/O-bound operations or [TPL in general](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for CPU-bound tasks.